# Can my SSH session be detected by sysadmin?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, mac-address

My friend gets faster internet in my university as he has some research scholar facilities.Our sysadmin has made sure this feature can be only accessed by a few machines with a particular MAC addresses. MAC spoofing has been detected by him by some means and hence that theory has already been put to a test.

Now, can I make a SSH tunnel and use his network without being detected the same way as MAC spoof? Will all the usage be shown as done by him or can I somehow be seen that there is an SSH tunnel active that has been using a research scholar's internet? If not, will creating multiple SSH hops be any good?

One last thing.How exactly is a private key of any use while doing an SSH? Will it help in giving any form of anonymity from the sysadmin?

Thanks!
Sai

Comment: ummmm, dude, just give it up. yes, a network admin with sufficient ability to analyze traffic could definitely detect an SSH connection to the host, and where it came from. the admin will probably not be able to see the traffic coming out of the machine and deterime that its source is remote, but they can definitely see the traffic coming into the machine. SSH encrypts the data region of the packets, but does nothing to hide the IP address or other identifiers in the packet below the transport layer.

Comment: oh, and study up on Diffie-Hellman style cryptography. you are miles off on the meaning of private keys. Either way, cryto will only keep them from breaking in to the tunnel and reading the contents of your packets. they can still see that you are connecting to the remote machine over ssh. changing port numbers will not matter, since SSH has an identifiable packet signature to someone who can sniff the traffic. encrypting your data does NOTHING to protect your privacy/anonymity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the environment:

- You are at a machine that I call `home`.
- You have SSH access to a machine in the university, I'll call it `univ`.
- `univ`'s MAC address is white-listed, so it has access to that privileged network.

So, yes, you can easily create an SSH tunnel:

```
you@home$ ssh -D 1234 you@univ
```

This will create a SOCKS proxy listening to `home` port `1234`, and redirecting traffic through `univ` machine. You can then configure this proxy in your browser.

---

Can this be detected? Of course!

- The sysadmin can notice some amount of traffic in the network.
- The traffic can be clearly tracked down to the `univ` machine.
- The sysadmin can inspect the machine to monitor the connections.
- The ssh connection can be clearly detected, including the username used in the connection.

So, yes, the sysadmin can detect it. No, it won't be the same procedure as MAC spoofing. And using username+password or username+key makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a way to get your 'friend' in trouble.  The sysadmin can almost certainly see the existence of communication between the privileged host, and other systems within the network.  The sysadmin can also probably see outgoing communication from the privileged host to the rest of the world.  So even if he doesn't see your SSH session, he may believe your friend is abusing his privilege.

As for the PKI employed, the purpose of it is exactly opposite of anonymization.  PKI is used as a method to authenticate that the and user are actually who they claim to be.